# Производить ли проверку на наличие объекта перед операцией создания и изменения

Tags: java, mvc, crud

Есть веб приложение реализующее CRUD операции. Я видел много кода где не осуществляется проверка наличия объекта в бд. 
Должен ли я проверять наличие объекта в БД перед созданием и изменением и если да то что принято возвращать Exception или иное значение.Почему да или почему нет? 
И где принято прозводить валидацию данных у контроллеров или сервисов(Уровень сервисов или уровень бизнес логики) для сервисов

Т.е. представленный код с перехватом исключений на уровне выше

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

    public Category addCategory(Category category){
        return categoryRepo.save(category);
    }

    public Category updateCategory(Long id,Category category){
        category.setId(id);
        return categoryRepo.save(category);
    }

}
```

Или представленный код ниже и проверка на уровне выше на null

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

    public Optional<Category> addCategory(Category category){
        Optional<Category> categoryDB = categoryRepo.findByName(category.getName());

        if (categoryDB.isPresent())
            return Optional.empty();

        return categoryRepo.save(category);
    }

    public Optional<Category> updateCategory(Long id,Category category){
        Optional<Category> categoryDB = categoryRepo.findById(category.getId());

        if (!categoryDB.isPresent())
            return Optional.empty();

        categoryDB.setDataCategory(category); 

        return categoryDB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Наличие/отсутствие объекта в БД после проверки может измениться

Comment: т.е. это зависит от количества операций в короткий момент времени

Comment: Нет. От количества подключенных пользователей. Пока у вас к базе подключен ровно один пользователь и база находится в монопольном доступе, вы можете быть уверенным, что состояние после проверки не поменяется. Как только пользователей более одного, вы не можете быть уверены ни в чем. Именно поэтому есть такие SQL операторы как `MERGE`, `INSERT OR UPDATE` etc

Comment: Как определить норму при которой использовать какой из подходов?

Comment: Я же написал - если одновременно подключенных пользователей больше одного, то проверять заранее бессмысленно